# Synchronize at most derived destructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, destructor

I encountered a crash from calling a pure virtual method, due to a race condition where other threads are still calling methods of a derived class when it's already destroyed. Here's the gist of it:

```
class Resource
{
protected:
    Resource();
    virtual ~Resource();

public:
    virtual void *lock_shared() = 0;
    virtual void unlock_shared() = 0;

    // Wait for all other threads to finish.
    void sync()
    {
        mutex.lock();
        mutex.unlock();
    }

protected:
    std::shared_mutex mutex;
};

Resource::~Resource()
{
    sync();
}

class Image : public Resource
{
public:
    Image();
    ~Image() override;

    void *lock_shared() override
    {
        mutex.lock_shared();

        return accessData();
    }

    void unlock_shared() override
    {
        processData();

        mutex.unlock_shared();
    }
};
```

Note that when an object of type Image gets destroyed, the intention is to wait for all threads with shared access to finish. However, due to the C++ destructor calling order, `Image::~Image()` is done by the time we `sync()` in `Resource::~Resource`, meaning the object is no longer of type `Image`, and we can't call any of `Image`'s methods. Other threads still holding a lock will however try to call `Image::unlock()` when they're done, resulting in a pure virtual call to `Resource::unlock()` and aborting the program.

The apparent solution is simple: call `sync()` in `Image::~Image()` instead.

Unfortunately this is very prone to happening again whenever I derive a new class from `Resource`, or, from `Image`. I've added an `assert()` to `Resource::~Resource()` to check that `try_lock()` is always successful, but that doesn't help when I derive from `Image`.

So I was wondering if anyone knows a more foolproof way to prevent this race condition once and for all. Thanks.

Comment: Just locking and unlocking the mutex is never going to give you thread safety. Another thread may come in just after the unlock but before the function returns/the object is destroyed. To be safe you'd have to hold the mutex across the enire destruction of the object (that is; outside of it).

Comment: This sounds brittle. How about a nice `std::shared_ptr` and a method other than object destruction to signal exit?

Answer (score 4):

As an idea, if you are ok with using some factory for creating objects of classes derived from `Resource` rather than explicitly create them, you can make this factory return `std::unique_ptr<DerivedResource>` with custom deleter which would call `p_obj->sync()` before actually deleting an owned instance of `p_obj`.

Comment: In my opinion, factories should always return `std::unique_ptr`. If that's all the caller needs it's nice and efficient. If the caller needs shared ownership she can always store the return value in a `std::shared_ptr` herself and "upgrade" to shared ownership. There's no reason for the factory to force shared ownership (and the overhead that implies) on its user.

Comment: Thank you for the remark, I totally agree with you on that point.

Comment: glad we agree - and I see you updated your answer to no longer  return `std::shared_ptr` +1 :)

Comment: `shared_ptr` was rather my default assosiation with 'custom deleter' than a conscious choice for a factory) again, thanks for pointing out this detail.

Comment: Even if I agree in general case, note that using `std::make_shared` has (micro) optimization over `std::make_unique` converted to `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Again, if it is critical for a particular application - it's always possible to have both versions of create methods.